# Switch cases, php

Tags: php, switch, case

У меня есть переменная, которая принимает значения: 0, 1, 2, 3

Сделаны у меня через switch следующие действия:

```
switch($var) {
  case 0:
   func(0);
   break;
  case 1:
   func(1);
   break;
  case 2:
   another_func(2);
   break;
  case 3:
   another_func(3);
   break;
}
```

Собственно, я собираюсь добавить теперь значение 4, которое будет исполнять тоже самое, что 2 и 3 вместе, в данном примере то есть последовательно функции **another_func(2)** и **another_func(3)**. Как это сделать, чтоб не переписывать одно и тоже?

Answer (score 2):

Для такого вам лучше использовать не `switch` а `if` с битовым сравнением и флаги в качестве переключателей

Пример:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{

    const FIRST_OPTION = 1 << 0;
    const SECOND_OPTION = 1 << 1;
    const THIRD_OPTION = 1 << 2;
    const FOURTH_OPTION = 1 << 3;

    public function test($option)
    {
        if (static::FIRST_OPTION & $option) {
            echo "First option selected\n";
        }
        if (static::SECOND_OPTION & $option) {
            echo "Second option selected\n";
        }
        if (static::THIRD_OPTION & $option) {
            echo "Third option selected\n";
        }
        if (static::FOURTH_OPTION & $option) {
            echo "Fourth option selected\n";
        }
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->test(static::FIRST_OPTION | static::FOURTH_OPTION);
    }
}
```

Если нужно все-таки со `switch`-ем, то можно вот так "выкрутиться":

```
switch($option) {
    case 0:
        echo "func(0)\n";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "func(1)\n";
        break;
    case 2:
    case 4:
        echo "another_func(2)\n";
        if ($option != 4) break;
    case 3:
        echo "another_func(3)\n";
        break;
}
```

но я бы не рекомендовал, конечно... Код получается не очень понятный, да и `switch` для таких конструкций не предназначен. Опускать `break` более менее допустимо если для нескольких вариантов используется один обработчик, как тут:

```
switch($beer)
{
    case 'tuborg';
    case 'carlsberg';
    case 'heineken';
        echo 'Хороший выбор';
    break;
    default;
        echo 'Пожалуйста, сделайте новый выбор...';
    break;
}
```

Это из [оф. инструкции](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php) если что ))

Comment: Да я хотел бы именно со свитчем это сделать. Я просто в нем не сильно разбираюсь, но разве нельзя расположить их в каком-то нужном порядке, где-то убрать break; чтоб получилось? У меня пока логика не выстраивается, как это нужно сделать.

Comment: @Shevsky Теоретически можно, да. Вот тут похожий пример есть: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070451/switch-for-bitwise-comparison

Comment: Пока единственное решение, которое я придумал: http://pastebin.com/c2GcAHR4

Comment: @Shevsky а почему именно свитч нужен?

Comment: для саморазвития, так сказать, чтоб логику и фишки его работы выучить, да в дальнейшем использовать.

Comment: @Shevsky добавил в ответ рабочий вариант со свитчем, без дублирующихся вызовов

Answer (score 2):

Не рекомендую использовать switch-case конструкции или же if-else, когда речь идет о добавлении новых элементов, поверьте мне - это всегда **накладно и ооочень плохо** :).

Могу предложить вам воспользовать данным решением, которое подойдет, даже если ваша переменанная будет принимать 1000 значений - оно будет работать прекрасно!!!

```
function foo($var)
{
    echo $var;
}

function bar(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

function handler($var, $callback)
{
    call_user_func($func, $callback);
}

$var = 1;
handler($var, 'foo') // Выведет 1 на экран

$var = 2;
handler($var, 'bar') // прибавит к $var + 1;
```

Данная операция избегает **ОГРОМНОГО** дублирования кода в вашем проекте\случае. Разъесняю, что и как. Метод `handler($var, $callback)` принимает два аргумента: `$var` - это наша *динамическая* переменная, второй аргумент `$callback`, используемые для вызова [callback-функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Можете дописать данный код и подумать над дальнейшей его реализации, скорее всего вам придется писать собственный класс(в идеале), для обработки вашей переменной - ваши возможности ограничены только фантазией :)

Хорошего дня и глубоких знаний в программировании!

[call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) - об методе

Answer (score 0):

По другому никак, это же логика приложения.

Никто кроме вас не знает, что нужно делать по 4, или если это будет использоваться чаще, чем 1 раз

- прописывайте another_funcs(1,2), которая делает another_func(1),another_func(2)

То, что вы делаете совместно в комментариях выше, играясь с "break" - усложняет (в том числе и вам самим) чтение логики кода в последствии, несмотря на то, что решение будет работоспособно.